# Get video.mp4 video tag from nodejs streaming

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, video, streaming

I building a streaming service from nodejs. This Is my server code server.js

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    util = require('util');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var path = __dirname+'/movie.mp4';
  var stat = fs.statSync(path);
  var total = stat.size;
  if (req.headers['range']) {
    var range = req.headers.range;
    var parts = range.replace(/bytes=/, "").split("-");
    var partialstart = parts[0];
    var partialend = parts[1];

    var start = parseInt(partialstart, 10);
    var end = partialend ? parseInt(partialend, 10) : total-1;
    var chunksize = (end-start)+1;
    console.log('RANGE: ' + start + ' - ' + end + ' = ' + chunksize);

    var file = fs.createReadStream(path, {start: start, end: end});
    res.writeHead(206, { 'Content-Range': 'bytes ' + start + '-' + end + '/' + total, 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Content-Length': chunksize, 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' });
    file.pipe(res);
  } else {
    console.log('ALL: ' + total);
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Length': total, 'Content-Type': 'video/mp4' });
    fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(res);
  }
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

This is my Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>


    <body>
      <video scr="http://localhost:1337" preload autoplay controls></video>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The video tag doesn't show any video but when i type the address http://localhost:1337 in the address of my browser, it plays video.

How can get the video it in a video tag im my page? May be I shoud use some js code client side?

Comment: Could you please tell me what your code exactly does ? why you do not use ffmpeg?

Comment: I have this issue with ffmpeg wihtout solution for the moment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41916054/how-to-make-ffserver-stream-my-file . Search for solution :(

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Syntax Error in my video tag "src" not "scr"